# Indexing is not applying on the date column in postgres. Top-N-heapsort is applying not Index scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, heapsort, postgresql-12

I have a table 'post' which has millions of rows. I need top N records using the date field but it's taking too much time because of Top-N-heapsort. How can I optimize this query?

Note: On the staging server where I have less data it's working fine. Index scan is applying there.

DB Version: Postgres 12

```
    CREATE TABLE public.posts
(
    post_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT (primary key),
    team_id integer NOT NULL,
    is_active boolean DEFAULT true,
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone,
)
```

Index column are:

```
"createdAt DESC NULLS Last",
(team_id ASC NULLS LAST, "createdAt" DESC NULLS LAST),
team_id ASC NULLS LAST
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE team_id = 1
AND p.is_active = true AND "createdAt" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Query plan:

```
 "Limit  (cost=138958.67..138958.72 rows=20 width=360) (actual time=356.391..356.419 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=138958.67..139078.57 rows=47960 width=360) (actual time=356.389..356.402 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: ""createdAt"" DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 34kB"
"        ->  Index Scan using posts_team_id on posts p  (cost=0.44..137682.47 rows=47960 width=360) (actual time=0.042..317.258 rows=52858 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (team_id = 1)"
"              Filter: (is_active AND (""createdAt"" IS NOT NULL))"
"Planning Time: 0.145 ms"
"Execution Time: 356.459 ms"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the index I would use:

```
CREATE INDEX ON posts (team_id, "createdAt") WHERE is_active;
```

It supports the `WHERE` condition and the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: will give it a try tonight but inactive post count is very less. it's in hundreds

Comment: Then you can omit the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: I already have this index as I mentioned in the question.
(team_id ASC NULLS LAST, "createdAt" DESC NULLS LAST)

Comment: No, you don't, because you specified `NULLS LAST` both times. That makes a difference.

Comment: Ok.. will try this

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE team_id = 1 AND
      p.is_active = true AND
      "createdAt" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "createdAt" DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

I would suggest writing this without the `is not null` and creating an index on `(team_id, is_active, createdAt desc)`.

Comment: not working... its taking top-N-heapsort only

Answer (score 0):

It won't use a DESC NULLS LAST index to support an ORDER BY...DESC NULLS FIRST query.  (NULLS FIRST is the default for DESC when nothing is specified, so that is what your query is doing).

It seems rather weird that you would go out of your way to specify an ordering in the index, but not make it match your query.

Either your stage server has a different index, or is running a different query.